# DCMMKDIR creating new files instead of appending

Tags: command-line, dicom

I have a C# application that uses DCMMKDIR.exe to create a DICOMDIR file out of a bunch of DICOM files. My problem with this is that it does not put the information in the DICOMDIR file but instead creates it's own file name something similar to Dda11008. My command line and args are as follows:

```
dcmmkdir  +A +r +u +I -nb --input-directory " + studyLocation + " --output-file " + dicomdirlocation + @"\DICOMDIR"
```

These are the files created:
[image]

As you can see the DICOMDIR is 0kb in size and has nothing in it.

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating part 10 compliant DICOM Media, you should prepare the individual DICOM file to match the part 10 requirement. This should include a 128 byte File Preamble, followed by a 4 byte DICOM prefix "DICM", followed by the File Meta Elements such as follows:

- File Meta Information Group Length (0002,0000)
- File Meta Information Version (0002,0001)
- Media Storage SOP Class UID (0002,0002)
- Media Storage SOP Instance UID (0002,0003)
- Transfer Syntax UID (0002,0010)
- Implementation Class UID (0002,0012)

Follow the file naming and folder structure convention as defined in the standard. They include following:

- DICOMDIR location should be at the root directory
- Filename should be limited to 8 characters and no extension. G0 repertoire of ISO 8859  (e.g. upper case A-Z and 0 to 1 plus the “_” (underscore))
- Directory structure: it may contain one to eight components (sub directory) and each component should be limited to 16 characters max from the subset of the G0 repertoire

Also make sure to have the unique ID for each level of DICOM hierarchical model (Patient ID, Study Instance UID, Series Instance UID and SOP Instance UID).
Having the above information will help facilitate creation of a proper DICOMDIR

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have not had time to look into it yet, but I get what you're saying. I'll respond when I get a chance. Thank you!